# Rmarkdown tabular data cards

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown, tabular

I am trying to produce nice PDF output from a survey detailing **properties of training places** according to trainee provided information - one row per training. I have a dataframe where each row contains description of a training - like `TrainingName - TrainingType - TrainingLocation - WhoPays(opt1, opt2,opt3) - AdditionalNotes`; length of each data piece can vary considerably. `kableExtra` is very good, but it really gives me a way how to display the data frame, not how to make custom layouts.

So to process this I thought I would use something like this in a for loop within a markdown chunk:

```
Title: `r dataframe$TrainingName[i]`
Type: `r dataframe$TrainingType[i]`  Location: `r dataframe$TrainingLocation[i]`
etc...
\newline
```

The idea is to process the data table row by row and making a mini table layout sructure for each training. Essentially it would be like creating a series of item properties card structures for each training. A bit like that, but more serious:

[image: A property card]

I am thinking that I could try to make a markdown table output which then to convert to latex, but thought - there must be easier ways. **Does anyone have an idea how to produce such a card-like structure from each data table row?** The table would be first row - 2 cells, second row 4 cells, third row 4 cells, fourth row - 1 cell.

Comment: Create a function that takes on one row and puts the data in format ... more detailed answers are not really possible without example data.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am wondering if it is possible to make a table row by row  and how then it could be passed to be rendered via knitr